# Consistently handling network partitions and split-brain scenarios in Akka

Tags: scala, akka, distributed-computing, akka-cluster

It looks like akka.cluster.split-brain-resolver is a paid-for feature. (I got that impression from [this line in the docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/rp-15v09p02/scala/split-brain-resolver.html)):

> This is a feature of the Typesafe Reactive Platform that is exclusively available for Typesafe Project Success Subscription customers.

Does this mean I'm going to have to pay to have a strategy for handling network partitions that result in a split-brain, or is there a way to handle network partitions that is available open-source?

I have a cluster singleton that I want to be running on whichever partition has the majority of nodes connected in a dynamically scaling cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Split Brain Resolver require Typesafe reactive Platform subsciption for production usage

https://www.lightbend.com/blog/how-to-handle-network-partitions-decisively-with-akka-split-brain-resolver

Comment: The crux of the question was more on the "is there a way to handle network partitions that is available open-source" side

Comment: Sorry, But I don't know any ready open-source SBR implementation